# Sending Variables to Method for addition

Tags: java, methods, addition

I've been implementing a program to add two numbers using `JTextField`.

I've been able to make it run, however I want to change the code so that the values from the `JTextField` are sent to the method file (which is in the same folder) to be added together.  Once the values have been added I  want the answer sent back to a third `JTextField` to display the answer.  I have set it up so that when a `JButton` is pressed, the method is called, however I do not know how to go about writing the method and getting the answer in the third `JTextField`.

Here is my code, class A being format and class B being the method file:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class A implements ActionListener {
    JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3;
    JButton b1;
    
    A() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("Enter First Value");
        myLabel.setBounds(50, 50, 150, 20);
        tf1 = new JTextField();
        tf1.setBounds(50, 75, 250, 20);
        JLabel mysecondLabel = new JLabel("Enter Second Value");
        mysecondLabel.setBounds(50, 125, 150, 20);
        tf2 = new JTextField();
        tf2.setBounds(50, 150, 250, 20);
        tf3 = new JTextField();
        tf3.setBounds(160, 225, 140, 20);
        tf3.setEditable(false);
        b1 = new JButton("Sum");
        b1.setBounds(50, 225, 95, 20);
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        f.add(tf1);
        f.add(myLabel);
        f.add(tf2);
        f.add(mysecondLabel);
        f.add(tf3);
        f.add(b1);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s1 = tf1.getText();
        String s2 = tf2.getText();
        int x = Integer.parseInt(s1);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(s2);
        int z = 0;
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            B b = new B();
            b.mymethod();
        }
        String result = String.valueOf(z);
        tf3.setText(result);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A();
    }
}
```

```java
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;

public class B {
    
   public static void mymethod() {
       int x, y;
       int z = x + y; 
   }      
}
```

Comment: B.myMethod() should not compile. x, y, z are not defined. You need parameters.

Comment: @NomadMaker thanks for the reply. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Something like ``public static int myMethod(int x, int y) { return x + y; }

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like:

```
try {
  int a = Integer.valueOf(tf1.getText());
  int b = Integer.valueOf(tf2.getText());
  int sum = a + b;
  tf3.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  tf3.setText("Evaluation error: " + e.getMessage();
}
```

BTW, your helper method `mymethod()` was probably supposed to take in parameters and return a value, rather than assign it to yet another local variable?

```
static int sum(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `JButton` where you've defined: `b1.addActionListener(this);` - this line says "when the jbutton is called, execute the actionListener referred to by `this`.... `this` 'implements' `ActionListener`, which means your class has a method: `actionPerformed` that receives an `ActionEvent` (which essentially tells the action listener where the event originated).

Because your class implements the ActionListener method `actionPerformed()`, this is the method that is invoked when your button is clicked.

Your actionPerformed method attempts to get values from `B` by calling `mymethod()` which doesn't work. This is because the variables are local only to class `B`. If you want them to appear in class `A` you need to declare class `B` more like:

```java
public class B {
    
    public static int x() {
        return 5;
    }

    public static int y() {
        return 15; 
    }

    public static int mymethod(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Then for class `A`'s action performed method you'd write:

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
    if(e.getSource()!=b1){  
        return;  
    }
    String s1 = tf1.setText(B.x()); // X
    String s2 = tf2.setText(B.y()); // Y
    
    int x = Integer.parseInt(s1.getText());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(s2.getText());
               
    String result = B.mymethod(x, y);

    tf3.setText(result);  // set the value of tf3 to X + Y
}
```

If you wanted to have the button just add up whatever is in the text fields, you can just remove the two lines that set the text to `B.x()` and `B.y()`.

Beware of the exceptions that will occur though if you put anything other than a valid integer into the two text fields. You may want to handle these. Ints also have a maximum value so simply adding two integers will max out at `(2^31) - 1` see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE